# Popup window in android WebView

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using `webview` to open a link in my app. The link works fine in `webview` but when i clicked on an item of webview(link opened) which open a popup my app got crashed. and gives me error .

```
03-24 16:40:10.680: W/System.err(5798): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@421e0760 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-24 16:40:10.680: W/System.err(5798):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:536)
03-24 16:40:10.680: W/System.err(5798):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
03-24 16:40:10.680: W/System.err(5798):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-24 16:40:10.680: W/System.err(5798):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupDialog.show(SelectPopupDialog.java:217)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.showSelectPopup(ContentViewCore.java:2413)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-24 16:40:10.690: W/System.err(5798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am opening webview like this.

```
Intent it = new Intent(MyMainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
                    it.putExtra("url", url);
                    ParentActivity parent = (ParentActivity) getParent();
                    parent.startChildActivity("WebViewActivity", it);
```

My WebViewActivity code is this.

```
String url = in.getStringExtra("url");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);

        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: post your all code and logcat

Comment: @ Simple Plan, Please have a look. i have edited my question.

Comment: No no user i m talk in about client code. your web view client code where you have to set Pop Up window.

Comment: i am not setting that popup because i am using webview that popup is the part of the link i opened in my webview.

Answer (score 0):

You can add webview programmatically instead of layout file.

1. Replace your WebView with LinearLayout (or any appropriate) and get instance of that Layout.
2. Create new WebView in you Activity dynamically.

Code below:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    urls = getIntent().getStringExtra("key_url");
    linearWeb = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.webviewLayout);
    webView = new WebView(getParent());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linearWeb.addView(webView);
    showBox();
}

public void showWebView() {
    if (!((Activity) getParent()).isFinishing()) {
        setUpAction();
    }
}

private void setUpAction() {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(urls)) {

        webView.loadUrl(urls);
        this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
    }
}
```